# How do I disable or remove the "replace" checkbox of NSTextFinder?

Tags: cocoa

My app displays a logfile in an `NSTextView`. I want the user to be able to search the output using the find bar, but not be able to replace any text. The `NSTextView` is set to be not editable, but when I press cmd-F, the find bar shows a "replace" checkbox:

[image]

I can prevent the user from being able to actually replace any text by implementing the `NSTextViewDelegate` protocol methods `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:` and 
`textView:shouldChangeTextInRanges:replacementStrings:` but this does not remove or disable the checkbox. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`NSTextFinder` won’t present the **Replace** box if its `findBarContainer`’s `editable` property is `NO` (`false`).

You can set the property in code (the API is in the rarely-used superclass, `NSText`) or uncheck the box in Interface Builder.

Comment: I don't have an actual `NSTextFinder` object in the XIB nor do I instantiate one. The `NSTextView` has it's `editable` property set to `NO` though.

Comment: Per the documentation, the `editable` property is actually on the `client` property, not the `findBarContainer`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfinderclient?language=objc I'd love a way to disable this via the `findBarContainer` because that would be easier to do without subclassing, but I haven't found a way.