# NSTextFinder on NSOutlineView show only the Find view

Tags: swift, macos

I have an outline view that uses a Find and Replace view entirely created in Interface Builder which works great in Mojave, but in old OSes (Yosemite is the deployment target) constraints goes crazy. After tens and tens of attempts I decide to explore other ways. NSTextFinder looks great and in fact the Find view appear to be good... but here the problem: only the Find view appear even if I told to show the Replace one. This is the sample code to reproduce the issue:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFinderClient {
  @IBOutlet var outline :NSOutlineView! 
  var textFinder : NSTextFinder?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.textFinder = NSTextFinder()
    self.outline.enclosingScrollView!.findBarPosition = .aboveContent
    self.textFinder?.findBarContainer = self.outline.enclosingScrollView
    self.textFinder?.client = self
    self.textFinder?.incrementalSearchingShouldDimContentView = true
  }

  @objc func performFindPanelAction(_ sender: Any) {
    //self.textFinder?.performAction(NSTextFinder.Action.showFindInterface)
    self.textFinder?.performAction(NSTextFinder.Action.showReplaceInterface)
  }
}
```

After this first attempt, I don't know how to connect actions but to start will be great to know why the Replace view doesn't appear.

Comment: See [How do I disable or remove the “replace” checkbox of NSTextFinder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620390/how-do-i-disable-or-remove-the-replace-checkbox-of-nstextfinder)

Comment: Hi Willeke thanks for the hint, print(self.textFinder?.client?.isEditable) says nil so I added let isEditable : Bool = true to my ViewController but still the same, though now says is editable..

Comment: `NSTextFinder` validates the UI. You don't get a replace button if the client can't replace. See [Text Finder Client Implementation Requirements](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfinder?language=objc).

Comment: @Willeke, any idea on how to deceive it?

Comment: Any way on the NSTextView it works good, but I've now also realize that Find view is not the same as Replace view, so Apple just replace them entirely on the fly, i.e. not like I do until now with a single view that I resize using the height constraint. May be I can just do the same exact thing.

Comment: I succeded, but w/o NSTextFinder.